# Models for small single object tracking

Tags: computer-vision

I need to track the position of a soccer ball during a soccer video clip. I currently use a YOLO detector plus a tracker to try to fill in gaps where the ball is not visible. Several problems arise:

- Being a small object it confuses the detection a lot.
- Sometimes it is not possible to determine if a sequence of predictions is really a ball or not.
- I would like to extract features such as: the ball is in the air, on the ground, etc...

Based on this I am looking for a model (maybe end-to-end) to implement ball detection+tracking.

**Input:** batch of images BxCxHxW representing a video clip fragment (B frames) (H, W should be greather than 720p to detect the ball)

**Output:** a Bx5 tensor with the ball box information (4 positions) and a parameter representing if the ball is in the air or not.

I am not looking for any dataset, but some idea about a model that can be trained with this data.

I have tried:

- Detection + usual tracking.
- Using a RNN to store sequence information.
- Transformer Encoder to pass a sequence of images (previously passing a CNN to generate a feature vector for each one).
- Several CNN to pass from BxCxHxW -> BxHxW (heat maps) -> Bx5, using the number of frames as number of channels.

I have not achieved good results. I don't know if the approaches are correct or I'm failing in the implementation. I have also had problems to be able to train all this because it doesn't fit in the GPU

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.